# How to understand the order of this code running

Tags: java

As I know, the order of code running is top down. So when call 2 method book.ship(), chemistrySet.ship() at the bottom, I think the 1st one should be called first. So why the result shows as below:

```
High value item!
Shipping
Shipping cost: 1.75
Order not ready
```

For the book instance, the cost = 9.99, but it still shows `High value item!`. How can I figure this out?

```
public class Order {
  boolean isFilled; //true
  double billAmount; //9.99
  String shipping;   //Express
  
  public Order(boolean filled, double cost, String shippingMethod) {
        if (cost > 24.00) {
      System.out.println("High value item!");
    }
    isFilled = filled;
    billAmount = cost;
    shipping = shippingMethod;
  }
  
  public void ship() {
    if (isFilled) {
      System.out.println("Shipping");
      System.out.println("Shipping cost: " + calculateShipping());
    } else {
      System.out.println("Order not ready");
    }
  }
  
  public double calculateShipping() {
        // declare conditional statement here
      if (shipping.equals("Regular")) {
        return 0;
      } else if (shipping.equals("Express")){
        return 1.75;
      } else {return .50;}
    }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // do not alter the main method!
    Order book = new Order(true, 9.99, "Express");
    Order chemistrySet = new Order(false, 72.50, "Regular");
    
    book.ship();
    chemistrySet.ship();
    
  }
}
```

Comment: "High value item" isn't printed when shipping - it's printed by this constructor call: `Order chemistrySet = new Order(false, 72.50, "Regular");`. That happens before `book.ship()` is called.

Comment: One way you can verify what Jon said is to put a `System.out.println("Constructors are done");` after the line that creates the `chemistrySet`, then it will be more obvious which parts print which statement.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing happening here is the main() method, which is where the program starts:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // do not alter the main method!
    Order book = new Order(true, 9.99, "Express");            //(1)
    Order chemistrySet = new Order(false, 72.50, "Regular");  //(2)
    
    book.ship();                                              //(3)
    chemistrySet.ship();                                      //(4)
    
}
```

1. You call the constructor method of the class for "book":

   ```
   public Order(boolean filled, double cost, String shippingMethod) {
       if (cost > 24.00) {
         System.out.println("High value item!");
       }
       isFilled = filled;
       billAmount = cost;
       shipping = shippingMethod;
   }
   ```

   And nothing is printed because *cost <  24.00*.
2. Now you call the constructor again for "chemistrySet", but this time it prints "High value item!" because its *cost > 24.00*
3. You call `book.ship()` and, since `filled == true`, it prints: *Shipping* and *Shipping cost: 1.75*
4. Now you call `chemistrySet.ship()`, but this time `isFilled` equals false, so it prints *Order not ready*